# JavaFx Wrapped ListView

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I want a ListView in JavaFx which can add Items in the following manner.

[image]

The Items should be added horizontally and when limit is reached, the next Item should be added just below as shown in the image.

Do we have something like this in JavaFx? If not, how can we achieve this?

Kindly suggest.

Comment: If the limit is a certain number (e.g. 4) you can use a `GridPane` with some logic to calculate the row and column index. If the limit is a displaying limit (e.g. the item could not be displayed in the current row) you can take a look on `FlowPane` or `TextFlow`. Or you can use `TilePane` too.

Comment: TilePane seems to be a good option. How can we use TilePane as a control as it is a container? I mean, for ListView, ListCell is the child element which gets selected. How to use TilePane in that context?

Comment: Ah okay, so you actually want the the behaviour of the `ListView` also. That's a much more complicated thing. For that you can implement you own control or try to subclass `ListView` somehow to override the skin. Both approach exceeds the complexity limit for an SO question unfortunately.

Comment: okay. I got you. Thanks